# How can i find a string using contains in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a string using contains in powershell , but its not being found . Here is the code

```
$str = "/microsoft.web/sites/MyAppservice/Instances/1234"
Write-Host $str.ToLower()
if ($str.ToLower() -contains "myappservice") 
{
  write-host "got it"
}
```

it is not foiund , whereas it should be .
What is wrong with this ?

Comment: In short: [`-contains` / `-notcontains`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) are _collection operators_: they test if the LHS object is _equal in full_ to at least one element of the RHS collection. They are not to be confused with the  `.Contains()` .NET _method_ for _substring matching_.  While PowerShell has no equivalent operator for _literal_ substring matching, you can use `-like` with _wildcard expressions_ or `-match` with _regular expressions_, both of which are case-_insensitive_.

Answer (score 3):

You've mixed up `-contains`, which works on collections, and `.Contains`, which is a method on strings. Use this:

```
$str.ToLower().Contains("myappservice")
#=> True
```

Or this:

```
$str -like "*myappservice*"
```

You could use `-contains` if you split the string into an array and are looking for an exact match of an entire component:

```
$str.ToLower() -split '/' -contains "myappservice"
#=> True
```

But that won't match substrings:

```
$str.ToLower() -split '/' -contains "my"
#=> False
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `-like` or `-match` (regex) instead, they match case insensitively and so they don't need the ToLower() either:

```
$str = "/microsoft.web/sites/MyAppservice/Instances/1234"
if ($str -like "*myappservice*")
{
  write-host "got it"
}
```

As Mark Reed answers, `-contains` is for something else - see [the documentation "about Operators"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#comparison-operators) which say:

> The comparison operators also include operators that find or replace patterns in text. The (-match, -notmatch, -replace) operators use regular expressions, and (-like, -notlike) use wildcards *.

> Containment comparison operators determine whether a test value appears in a reference set (-in, -notin, -contains, -notcontains).